# Flash disabled in camera activity when HDR is enabled

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an intent that simply clicks an image for me and displays it on an ImageView, using the following code to call the camera:

```
 Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

It all seems to work fine, except that when HDR is turned on in the system camera application, the flash button gets disabled in my application, you can't turn the flash on. Neither does the camera provide an option to turn HDR off in my custom application.

If I go to the system provided camera application, and turn of HDR, then the flash feature gets enabled in my application.

Can anyone please suggest a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Vast majority of the Android devices, very likely including your test device as well, disable flash when HDR is enabled. Some Android devices, though, allow simultaneous use of both flash and HDR.

Comment: But we don't get the ability to enable/disable HDR in a custom application on such devices, so how to we enable flash on such devices, in a custom application, when HDR is enabled.

Comment: I don't think there is a certain way of enabling flash or securing that it will be on programmatically when you are setting HDR mode on. I presume the flash switched to FLASH_MODE_AUTO when HDR is enabled. But once again majority of devices will disable flash when HDR is turned on anyway.

Comment: Will have to live with this then I guess. Thanks anyways.